# vb.net get src links insade iframes with htmlagilitypack

Tags: vb.net, iframe, html-agility-pack, src

im using htmlagility and trying to get both `wanted1` and `wanted2`
the html code is like this

```
<div class='class1' id='id1'>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="wanted1"</iframe>
<iframe id="iframe" src="wanted2"</iframe>
</div>
```

but no luck can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  is a commented sample to get you started:

```
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Dim html As String = <![CDATA[<div class='class1' id='id1'>
                                        <iframe id="iframe1" src="wanted1"</iframe>
                                        <iframe id="iframe" src="wanted2"</iframe>
                                      </div>]]>.Value
        'load the html string to the HtmlDocument we defined
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)
        'using LINQ and some xpath you can target any node you want
        ' //iframe[@src] xpath passed to the SelectNodes function means select all iframe nodes that has src attribute
        Dim srcs = From iframeNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe[@src]")
                   Select iframeNode.Attributes("src").Value

        'print all the src you got
        For Each src In srcs
            Console.WriteLine(src)
        Next
```

make sure you learn about XPath.